Failed to parse body as FormData when uploading files to AWS S3 in Next.js
I'm trying to implement a file upload endpoint in Next.js 14 that saves files to AWS S3 using @aws-sdk/client-s3. I'm using the NextRequest.formData() method to parse the uploaded file. However, I'm running into an error:
Failed to parse body as FormData

Code:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION as string,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID as string,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string,
  },
})

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const formData = await req.formData() // Error occurs here
  const file: File | null = formData.get('file') as unknown as File

  if (!file) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'File is required' })
  }

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer())
  await uploadFileToS3({ file: buffer, fileName: file.name })

  return NextResponse.json({
      success: true,
    }, {
      status: 201,
    },
  )
}

const uploadFileToS3 = async ({ file, fileName }: { file: Buffer, fileName: string }) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    Key: `${fileName}`,
    Body: file,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
  }

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(params)
  await s3Client.send(command)
}

I am testing this endpoint with multipart/form-data requests in Postman, and I expect NextRequest.formData() to handle the parsing. I’ve verified that all environment variables are correctly set.

Are there extra conflicting headers in your request, maybe forgotten from other attempts?
